# What are movementX and movementY alternatives for touch events?

Tags: javascript

I know how to track mouse movements when it is moving over the canvas area.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var info = document.getElementById("info");

function getMovements(e) {
  info.innerHTML =  "x change: " + String(e.movementX) + " , y change: " + String(e.movementY);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getMovements);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color:bisque;
}
```

```html
<canvas id ="canvas" width=300, height=300></canvas>
<div id=info></div>
```

But how can I do same thing with `canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", getMovements);` event, when `e.movementX` & `e.movementY` doesnt work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no such properties because a touch event can have multiple touches. You can however add these properties to the touchevent yourself before calling your `getMovements` function.

```js
var previousTouch;
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];

    if (previousTouch) {
        // be aware that these only store the movement of the first touch in the touches array
        e.movementX = touch.pageX - previousTouch.pageX;
        e.movementY = touch.pageY - previousTouch.pageY;

        getMovements(e);
    };

    previousTouch = touch;
});
```

If you want to you can set the `previousTouch` to null in the `touchend` event to prevent a new touch to use the old `previousTouch` on it's first move.

```js
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
    previousTouch = null;
});
```

Comment: When I try your code it starts debug on the line `previousTouch = touch` is this code working on your machine and I've done sth wrong by replasing just prev listener with your?

Comment: `let` can be reassigned... it was because `let` defines a variable at the current scope, while `var` is hoisted to the global scope

Comment: error when `previousTouch = touch;` because touch is not defined. Please accept my edit and your code will work. I will tick it an an answer!

Comment: no worries! I just sometimes find myself figuring out a problem by reading the comments on an answer, so I figured for that next person, maybe I'll help avoid some confusion. :)

Comment: `var` is scoped to the *function* it's declared - not global scope. `let` is *block* scoped.